# Node.js passing parameters to my require function in express.js/passport.js? understanding why?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, passport.js

Hi guys I need some help understanding node.js syntax. The application has put parameters on a require function that requires a path to another file ( not a module). let me give you an example of the syntax that I am talking about which is located on the main javascript file called server.js.

```
require('./config/passport')(passport);
```

and

```
require('./app/routes.js')(app, passport);
```

I need to know why these "app" and "passport" parameters are passed to my require function. app is express and passport is the passport module.

the full relevant files are below. Cheers

```js
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
var port = process.env.PORT || 8080;
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var passport = require('passport');
var flash = require('connect-flash');
require('./app/models/user');

var morgan = require('morgan');
var cookieParser = require('cookie-parser');
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
var session = require('express-session');

var configDB = require('./config/database.js');

mongoose.connect(configDB.url);

require('./config/passport')(passport);

app.use(morgan('dev')); //http request logger
app.use(cookieParser()); //reads cookies (needed for authentication)
app.use(bodyParser()); //gets information from html forms

app.set('view engine', 'ejs');

//required for passport
app.use(session({secret: 'jonathanisawesome'}));
app.use(passport.initialize());
app.use(passport.session()); //persistent login sessions
app.use(flash()); //connect-flash for flash messages stored in sessions


//routes
require('./app/routes.js')(app, passport); //loads our routes and passes in our app and fully configured passport

app.listen(port);
console.log('the magix happens on port ' + port);
```

```js
app.get('/logout', function(req,res){
 req.logout();
 res.redirect('/');
});




//processing of the form
app.post('/login', passport.authenticate('local-login', {
 successRedirect: '/profile',
 failureRedirect: '/login',
 failureFlash : true
}));



app.post('/signup', passport.authenticate('local-signup', {

 successRedirect: '/profile',
 failureRedirect: '/signup',
 failureFlash : true
}));


  // route for facebook authentication and login
    app.get('/auth/facebook', passport.authenticate('facebook', { scope : 'email' }));

    // handle the callback after facebook has authenticated the user
    app.get('/auth/facebook/callback',
        passport.authenticate('facebook', {
            successRedirect : '/profile',
            failureRedirect : '/'
        }));

     app.get('/auth/google', passport.authenticate('google', { scope : ['profile', 'email'] }));

    // the callback after google has authenticated the user
    app.get('/auth/google/callback',
            passport.authenticate('google', {
                    successRedirect : '/profile',
                    failureRedirect : '/'
            }));


    

};



//route middleware to make sure a user is logged in
function isLoggedIn(req,res,next){
 //if user is authenticated in the session, carry on
 if(req.isAuthenticated())
  return next();

 //if they are not, redirect them to the homepage
 res.redirect('/');
};
```

```js
var LocalStrategy = require('passport-local').Strategy;
var FacebookStrategy = require('passport-facebook').Strategy;
var GoogleStrategy = require('passport-google-oauth').OAuth2Strategy;
var User = require('mongoose').model('User');
var configAuth = require('./auth');
var crypto = require('crypto');
module.exports = function(passport){
 //passport session setup
 //persistent login sessions
 //passport needs ability to serialize and unserialize users out of sessions


 //use to serialize the user for the session
 passport.serializeUser(function(user,done){
  done(null, user.id);
 });


 //deserialize user
 passport.deserializeUser(function(id,done){
  User.findById(id, function(err, user){
   done(err, user);
  });
 });

 //local signup
 //using named strategies one for login and one for signup
 //by default if there was no name it would be called 'local'

    passport.use('local-signup', new LocalStrategy({
        // by default, local strategy uses username and password, we will override with email
        usernameField : 'email',
        passwordField : 'password',
        passReqToCallback : true // allows us to pass back the entire request to the callback
    },
    function(req, email, password, done) {

        // asynchronous
        // User.findOne wont fire unless data is sent back
        process.nextTick(function() {

        
                // create the user
                var newUser = new User();

                // set the user's local credentials
                newUser.email    = email;
                newUser.password = password; //password is hashed on the model layer

                // save the user
                newUser.save(function(err,user) {
    if(err || !user){
    
    //error handling
    
    if(err.code===11000){ //email taken
     return done(null, false, req.flash('signupMessage', 'Sorry, the email '+newUser.email+' has been taken'));
    }else{ //its a hacker
     return done(null, false, req.flash('signupMessage', JSON.stringify(err)));
    
    }
    
                       }else{ 
                    return done(null, newUser);
      }
                });
              

        });

    }));

  passport.use('local-login', new LocalStrategy({
        // by default, local strategy uses username and password, we will override with email
        usernameField : 'email',
        passwordField : 'password',
        passReqToCallback : true // allows us to pass back the entire request to the callback
    },
    function(req, email, password, done) { // callback with email and password from our form

        // find a user whose email is the same as the forms email
        // we are checking to see if the user trying to login already exists
        User.findOne({ 'email' :  email }, function(err, user) {
            // if there are any errors, return the error before anything else
            if (err)
                return done(err);

            // if no user is found, return the message
            if (!user)
                return done(null, false, req.flash('loginMessage', 'No user found.')); // req.flash is the way to set flashdata using connect-flash

            // if the user is found but the password is wrong
            if (!user.authenticate(password))
                return done(null, false, req.flash('loginMessage', 'Oops! Wrong password.')); // create the loginMessage and save it to session as flashdata

            // all is well, return successful user
            return done(null, user);
        });

    }));


//facebook
    passport.use(new FacebookStrategy({
        clientID: configAuth.facebookAuth.clientID,
        clientSecret: configAuth.facebookAuth.clientSecret,
        callbackURL: configAuth.facebookAuth.callbackURL
      },
      function(accessToken, refreshToken, profile, done) {
            process.nextTick(function(){
                User.findOne({'facebook.id': profile.id}, function(err, user){
                    if(err)
                        return done(err);
                    if(user)
                        return done(null, user);
                    else {
                        var newUser = new User();
                        newUser.email = profile.emails[0].value;
                        newUser.password = new Buffer(crypto.randomBytes(16).toString('base64'), 'base64');
                        newUser.socialLogin.facebook.id = profile.id;
                        newUser.socialLogin.facebook.token = accessToken;
                        newUser.socialLogin.facebook.name = profile.name.givenName + ' ' + profile.name.familyName;
                        newUser.socialLogin.facebook.email = profile.emails[0].value;

                        newUser.save(function(err){
                            if(err) console.log(err)
                                
                            return done(null, newUser);
                        })
                        console.log(profile);
                    }
                });
            });
        }

    ));


     passport.use(new GoogleStrategy({

        clientID        : configAuth.googleAuth.clientID,
        clientSecret    : configAuth.googleAuth.clientSecret,
        callbackURL     : configAuth.googleAuth.callbackURL,

    },
    function(token, refreshToken, profile, done) {

        // make the code asynchronous
        // User.findOne won't fire until we have all our data back from Google
        process.nextTick(function() {

            // try to find the user based on their google id
            User.findOne({ 'google.id' : profile.id }, function(err, user) {
                if (err)
                    return done(err);

                if (user) {

                    // if a user is found, log them in
                    return done(null, user);
                } else {
                    // if the user isnt in our database, create a new user
                    var newUser = new User();
                        newUser.email = profile.emails[0].value;
                        newUser.password = new Buffer(crypto.randomBytes(16).toString('base64'), 'base64');
                    newUser.socialLogin.google.id    = profile.id;
                    newUser.socialLogin.google.token = token;
                    newUser.socialLogin.google.name  = profile.displayName;
                    newUser.socialLogin.google.email = profile.emails[0].value; // pull the first email

                    // save the user
                    newUser.save(function(err) {
                        if (err)
                            throw err;
                        return done(null, newUser);
                    });
                }
            });
        });

    }));



};
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take this example:

```
var session = require('express-session');
var MongoStore = require('connect-mongo')(session);

app.use(session({
    secret: 'foo',
    store: new MongoStore(options)
}));
```

As you can see MongoStore is meant to be used alongside session, so it depends on that module.

Answer (score 1):

This:

```
require('./config/passport')(passport);
```

is roughly equivalent to this:

```
var pp = require('./config/passport');
pp(passport);
```

To explain, `require('./config/passport')` returns a function that expects one argument.  You can call that function directly in the first form above or you can assign it to a variable and then call it.

Answer (score 0):

`require('./config/passport')` returns a function which expects `passport` as its parameter.

Answer (score 0):

I faced the problem using `require('./config/passport')(passport)` so I got solution as:

```
const passConfig = () => {
  return require('./config/passport')
}
passConfig(passport)
```